# ng grid enableColumnResize not working on Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, ng-grid

Is this a bug with IE that when I try to rezise a column by dragging the header, on the first click the resizer sticks with the mouse and I have to click it one more time to quit dragging. On all other browser I think the drag and drop works perfectly. Is this me Or you all facing this issue? Any workaround?

```
enableColumnResize: true,
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9EkdMgn6kXryHs7nxak8?p=preview

Comment: We experience the same issue on IE9.